# Google Chrome loses cookies

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-beta

I'm using Google Chrome beta.

Recently, I found all my saved authentications get lost when I close the window and reopen. It is not saving any passwords or "stay signed in" or "remember me in this computer". This applies to Gmail, Facebook, Yahoo, etc.

The issue is only with Chrome; Firefox and IE are still okay.

Is this something I messed up, or is it just Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like it can't access its Sqlite database. I've had this before when I've had an instance of Chrome locked up somewhere, and started another process. (That's Chrome for Linux, admittedly, which is still in beta.) One tell tale sign of that - the bookmarks didn't have the proper icons either.

Has this problem persisted across reboots? If you haven't rebooted since you first saw the problem, I suggest you kill Chrome, then bring up task manager and make sure that there aren't any more Chrome processes running. Then restart it and see if it's behaving any better.

Comment: restarting windows has resolved the issue, thanks