# Google Chrome loses authentication cookies on exit

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, cookies

I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise (64bit) and have tried both the current 2.x stable and 3.x beta versions of Chrome. Both of them lose any and all authentication cookies when I close the browser. This behavior persists after rebooting. Saved passwords remain, and bookmarks retain their icons, [unlike in this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/36348/chrome-loses-cookies)

My suspicion is that there may be a permissions issue of some sort but really I don't know where to start.

How can I get Chrome to remember my logins?

Comment: actually the computer date was set to 2012, that caused the whole issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling, then reinstalling did the trick. Not sure if I forgot this step the first time, but for the reinstall, I right clicked on the installer and ran as admin explicitly (even though my account is an admin account).

Comment: Uninstalling then reinstalling didn't fix it for me, but manually deleting the cookies file did.

Answer (score 3):

Go to

C:\Documents and Settings\ **YOUR USER NAME** \Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\

Find file 'Cookies' -- Delete it. Restart Chrome.

Comment: You did see this is over a year old and already answered, right?

Comment: Deleting this cookie file resolved the problem for me.

Comment: @oKtosiTe this answer is correct.  I had this exact issue and the accepted answer was wrong (probably because the user settings aren't deleted when you uninstall chrome).

Comment: Fair enough. @Hardwareguy